# Splitting the string with Regex yields unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have the following string and regex

```
const message = "asdasd :+1::skin-tone-4:"
const emojiRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+:(:skin-tone-[1-6]:)?)/g
```

When I use `.match(emojiRegex)` on `message`, I get the following result which is correct:

```
[":+1::skin-tone-4:"]
```

But when I try to use `.split(emojiRegex)` with the same regex I get the following result:

```
["asdasd ", ":+1::skin-tone-4:", ":skin-tone-4:", ""]
```

I expect this as a result:

```
["asdasd ", ":+1::skin-tone-4:", ""]
```

What's wrong here? How should I change my regex to have the expected result?

```js
const message = "asdasd :+1::skin-tone-4:"

const emojiRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+:(:skin-tone-[1-6]:)?)/g

console.log(message.match(emojiRegex));
console.log(message.split(emojiRegex));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the capturing group around `:skin-tone-[1-6]:`, as [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Splitting_with_a_RegExp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result):

> If `separator` is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses `()`, matched results are included in the array.

```js
const message = "asdasd :+1::skin-tone-4:"

const emojiRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+::skin-tone-[1-6]:?)/g

console.log(message.split(emojiRegex));
```

You could also use a non-capturing group `(?)?` and remove all elements from the result that are empty strings:

```js
const message = "asdasd :+1::skin-tone-4:"
const message2 = "asdasd :+1:"


const emojiRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+:(?:skin-tone-[1-6]:)?)/g

console.log(message.split(emojiRegex).filter(Boolean));
console.log(message2.split(emojiRegex).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: You can see the extra group being captured here:
https://regexr.com/3u8jk

Comment: well this gives me a correct result for this particular example but the second capturing group is not required in my case. but this change makes it required. It also needs to match with `:+1:` for example. how to also achieve that?

Comment: I added another method of doing this, which will work with just `:+1:` but will split the skin-tone from the emoji coming before it. You could add them back together though...

Comment: I think I'll use alternation

Comment: `/(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+::skin-tone-[1-6]:)|(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+:)/g` works for me.

Comment: Sure, that would also work. Maybe answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use capturing part in split regex. From mdn docs,

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array.

```js
const message = "asdasd :+1::skin-tone-4:"

const emojiRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+::skin-tone-[1-6]:)/g


console.log(message.split(emojiRegex));
```

Comment: well this gives me a correct result for this particular example but the second capturing group is not required in my case. but this change makes it required. It also needs to match with :+1: for example. how to also achieve that?